# What is Mappo Trell's actual stature?

Tags: malazan, steven-erikson

Does Steven Erikson provide any information to establish Mappo Trell's stature (height and build), at least relative to his contemporaries? I imagine him to be of similar size to Karsa Orlong, who Erikson envisions as around [8 feet tall](https://www.sffworld.com/2007/09/interview-steven-erikson/). Probably a little shorter, but also more robust. Erikson provides context around most of his large characters; people looking up at Icarium or Karsa, Icarium being slightly shorter than Karsa and of a comparitively slender build, etc. However, I cannot recall him giving such details on Mappo Runt, aside from Mappo being very physically robust.

I am 10% through Toll the Hounds, so please be careful with spoilers past that.

Comment: Just answered my own question reading through Dust of Dreams;

"Two of the figures were imposing; one broad and bestial, his skin the hue of burnished mahogany, his black braided hair hanging in greast coils. ... The other was taller, his skin..." 

The first is Mappo, the second is a human character who is probably quite tall for a human but certainly not as tall as Karsa or Icarium. Given some of the feats ascribed to Mappo, he must be exceptionally strong on a kilo per kilo basis. 

Location 17029 reading in the kindle app.

Answer (score 2):

### At the very least he is taller and broader than an average human

In Toll the Hounds Mappo walks into Quip's Bar

> *...a monstrous figure pushed its way in, shoulders squeezing through the frame, head ducking.*
>
> <sub>***Toll The Hounds -p. 309***</sub>

This would suggest that Mappo is substantially broader than the average human, having to squeeze through a doorway. It would also suggest that he would be a good head taller than even a tall human considering he had to duck to get through the door.

Then when Quip younger notices him

> *The barkeep coughed and slowly straightened, wiping at his mouth, blinking myopically as he lifted his gaze to take in the figure looming over him.*
>
> <sub>***Toll The Hounds -p. 309***</sub>

Quip has to look up to see all of the Trell, even when he has stood up straight, again giving the impression that Mappo is noticeably taller than a (we assume average sized) human, the addition of the word *looming* also emphasises that Mappo is much bigger than a human.

---

I have seen your comment, I haven't read Dust of Dreams so I do not who the human is that is compared to Mappo but he must be a very large above average human indeed